# OpenWeatherMap Weather Details

Tags: php, openweathermap

I wanted to display the weather from a user on my website with openweathermap. that works with the temperatures so far i wanted to display whether it is raining or cloudy that doesn't work. weather->main doesn't work can someone help me?
Here is my code

```
$url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=".$city.",".$land."&APPID=MYAPPIDf&units=metric";
    $json=file_get_contents($url);
    $data=json_decode($json);

    echo '<p>Temperature from: ', $data->city->name, ' (', $data->city->country, ')</p>';

    // the general information about the weather

    echo '<p><strong>Current:</strong> ', $data->list[0]->main->temp, '&deg; C</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Min:</strong> ', $data->list[0]->main->temp_min, '&deg; C</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Max:</strong> ', $data->list[0]->main->temp_max, '&deg; C</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Fells Like:</strong> ', $data->list[0]->main->feels_like, '&deg; C</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>actualy Weather:</strong> ', $data->list[0]->weather->main, '</p>';
    ?>
```

that's what it shows me on my website

[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z575y.png)

I've tried a few things but I can't do it myself

Comment: Try `var_dump($data->list[0]->weather);` to see what the structure of the data is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`weather` is an array, you must use an index to access the properties of one element :

```
echo $data->list[0]->weather[0]->main ;
```

Also, remove your API key from your question.